# CSS error in Safari, pages don't load

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, error

So recently I updated to OS El Capitan 10.11.2 and it has interfered with my Safari experience (I think). I am somehow not able to see any pages in my Google Drive (Docs, Slides, Sheets), but I can use every other site perfectly fine. I have tried force quitting, clearing history, but it hasn't fixed the problem.

I don't know if clearing the caches will fix it though.

When I open the error console in Safari it states the below about 14 times, then Safari reloads saying: "A problem occurred with this web page so it was reloaded." It will do this for forever until the tab is closed.

Invalid CSS property declaration at: *

At the moment the sites: Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Drawings don't work. And I am sure this problem is isolated to my machine since I can access those sites on other computers.

Also I have tried booting up in safe mode but I still can't access the sites.

Additional INFO:

OS X El Capitan 10.11.2

Safari Ver: 9.0.2

Macbook Pro (mid 2009)

Comment: Just to test if the invalid CSS property declaration is the actual cause of this, can you try [opening this page](https://georgegarside.com/o/se/css-star-test.html) which is an extremely simple page that writes 'It works' to the screen but also causes the same warning message?

Comment: @grgarside oddly it works perfectly fine..